# How to move a rectangle in a curved path in pygames?

Tags: python, pygame

moving a rectangle in a straight line on pygames is easy. But how do i implement gravity into the rectangle's path? Like instead of a straight path, move in an curved path. Perhaps, the image below will help you understand what i am trying to achieve. 
[image: Curved path]

Here is the code to move the rectangle in a straight path to the left.

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
display_width = 800
display_height  = 700
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
FPS = 30

x = 300
y = 100
while True:
    x -= 10
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (x, y, 50,50))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: [this question/answer might be useful to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551009/gravity-in-pygame)

Comment: I checked it out thanks! But @MANA624 answer was pretty much what i was looking for.

Comment: good deal. glad you found what you were looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y_speed = 0
x_speed = -10
gravity = -3 # Depending on how fast you want gravity to be
while True:
    x += x_speed
    y += y_speed
    y_speed += gravity
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (x, y, 50,50))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Having taken some Physics can help with programming. I would suggest looking into some basic kinematic equations if you're still confused

Comment: You are a life saver sir! Well, ill look into the basic kinematics equations then.