# How do I add gravity to a square in my simulator in pygame?---python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, gravity

I have no clue how to add a gravity mechanism to my square. Here is the code:

```
import pygame, sys
from colors import *
from random import randint
import particles

pygame.init()

#background = pygame.image.load("graphics//background.jpg")
#Background = pygame.Surface(background.get_size(), pygame.HWSURFACE)
#Background.blit(background, (0, 0))



grav_x = 2
grav_y = 2

global window, window_height, window_width, window_title
window_width, window_height = 800, 600
window_title = "particle game"
#title_icon = "graphics//icons//icon_title.jpg"
pygame.display.set_caption(window_title)
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height), 
pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)


particle_size = 40


#class Particle(object):
    #def __init__(self, Color, xpos, ypos):
        #pygame.draw.rect(window, Color, pygame.Rect(xpos, ypos, particle_size, particle_size))


class Hydrogen:
    def __init__(self, Color, xpos, ypos):
        #Particle.__init__(self, Color, xpos, ypos)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, Color, pygame.Rect(xpos, ypos, particle_size, particle_size))

hydrogen = Hydrogen

isRunning = True

window.fill(Color.LightGray)

while isRunning:
    pygame.display.update()

    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mx -= 20
    my -= 20

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            isRunning = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            hydrogen(Color.Purple, mx, my)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

The grav_x and grav_y are my measly attempts to create gravity.

### Here is an example of my program being run down here.

[image: ***example display***]

---

I have tried adding gravity to my class, but it never works out, and I'm stuck brain dead.

If anyone has any ideas please tell me.

Comment: What do you mean by `gravity`? Do you want a "common" gravity, like the one that we're all subject to on this planet, or do you want to have each particle with its own gravity attracting particles around it depending on mass and distance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551009/gravity-in-pygame

Comment: gravity as in the particles fall to the ground, like if you dropped a ball.

Comment: If that's the kind of gravity you want, @stolenmoment suggestion is correct. It's not like gravity "starts" the moment an object is free to fall, gravity is always there, but most of the times there's something blocking the fall. So your object should always be falling (accelerating), unless they have a block along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
import pygame, sys
from random import randint

pygame.init()

#background = pygame.image.load("graphics//background.jpg")
#Background = pygame.Surface(background.get_size(), pygame.HWSURFACE)
#Background.blit(background, (0, 0))



grav_x = 2
grav_y = 2

global window, window_height, window_width, window_title
window_width, window_height = 800, 600
window_title = "particle game"
#title_icon = "graphics//icons//icon_title.jpg"
pygame.display.set_caption(window_title)
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height), 
pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)


particle_size = 40


#class Particle(object):
    #def __init__(self, Color, xpos, ypos):
        #pygame.draw.rect(window, Color, pygame.Rect(xpos, ypos, particle_size, particle_size))


class Hydrogen:
    def __init__(self, Color, xpos, ypos, size):
        #Particle.__init__(self, Color, xpos, ypos)
        self.color = Color
        self.position = [xpos, ypos]
        self.size = size
        self.velocity = [0, 0]

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.position[0], self.position[1], self.size, self.size))

    def move(self):
        self.position[0] += self.velocity[0]
        self.position[1] += self.velocity[1]
        print(self.velocity)
        print(self.position)

    def gravity(self):
        self.velocity[1] += 0.1

    def floor_collide(self):
        if self.position[1] + self.size > window_height:
            self.position[1] = window_height - self.size
            self.velocity[1] = -0.5 * self.velocity[1]

hydrogen = Hydrogen((255, 255, 0), 50, 50, particle_size)

isRunning = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while isRunning:
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mx -= 20
    my -= 20

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            isRunning = False

    hydrogen.gravity()
    hydrogen.floor_collide()
    hydrogen.move()

    window.fill((150, 150, 150))
    hydrogen.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Some of it seems redundant now I have changed it, but I left it in. Also, since I did not have `settings.py` or the colors file I removed those, so you'll have to re-add them.

Answer (score 0):

In general, what you do too implement gravity is to accelerate each particle downward on each update. I don't know pygame, but it looks like your particles don't move at all, so you should add the idea of motion and changing the position of particles repeatedly.
I'd suggest setting a constant downward velocity first that is, subtract a constant from the y (or add, if the origin is at the top) and get that going.
Then, gravity becomes multiplying the y velocity by 1.1 (for instance, play with it!) on each update.

Comment: ill try, but its hard to manage gravity with classes :(, but thanks anyway :)